# Using Facelets files from library in web app

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jar, facelets

Is it possible to use Facelets files in my web application from a JAR that I have included in `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Structure is like this:

- web module

  - WEB-INF

    - lib

      - common-component.jar
  - pages

    - index.xhtml

Is it possible to serve pages from `common-component.jar` as well as pages from the web module itself?

Comment: Well, have you tried to begin with? If not, please do it. If you have any problem, then come here and ask it.

Comment: It depend of where are `.xhtml` files located in your `.jar` file.

Comment: I have tried setting an .xhtml file in the root of the jar, but i could not get it to show up in my web app.

Comment: Thank you BalusC for directing me in the right direction. That was indeed what I was looking for